ideal N-port Touchstone spec
Want to specify ideal i.e. frequency independent S-parameter N-port components in Touchstone file (v1 or v2), for import into circuit simulator.
The official specs don't mention how many frequency inputs are needed for ideal part. Is just one arbitrary value e.g. 1 GHz sufficient, or is a range required, and if so what range should be chosen that will avoid potential speed penalty issues - if any?
